# Javascripts and Apache Velocity

Tags: javascript, html, velocity

I would like to go into another web page when I check one checkbox, automatically. 
I have wrote a simple query in javascripts to do it but I don't be able to execute the javascripts code when I check a checkbox.
Looking the web page source, it render well this Velocity code

```
#url_for_facet_filter($field.name,$facet.name)
```

but I think that when I click on a checkbok, it doesn't execute the javascript automatically and I don't be able to go to another web page automatically.
The other part of my .vm file works good.
This is my Apache Velocity .vm file

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function selectFunction(url) {
        var goTo = url;
        window.location("goTo");
        }
</script>

#if($response.facetFields)
  <h2 #annTitle("Facets generated by adding &facet.field= to the request")>
    Field Facets
  </h2>
  #foreach($field in $response.facetFields)
    ## Hide facets without value
    #if($field.values.size() > 0)
      <span class="facet-field">$field.name</span>
      <ul>
        #foreach($facet in $field.values)
          <li>

 <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"
    onclick="javascript:selectFunction("#url_for_facet_filter($field.name,$facet.name)")"> 
 <label for="myCheckbox">$facet.name ($facet.count)</label>

          </li>
        #end
      </ul>
    #end  ## end if > 0
  #end    ## end for each facet field
#end      ## end if response has facet fields
```

Thank you very much for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're using `window.location` as a function instead of an object.  What you're looking for is `window.location.replace` which takes the URL as the next location.  Try changing `window.location(goTo);` to `window.location.replace(goTo)`.

Comment: Hm.  Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: I have deleted by mistake my reply to you. I'll rewrite it.

Thank you for your reply but I also tryed with `window.location.replace(goTo)` or `window.location.href=goTo;` but it doesn't work anyway.

However, thank you